# Google analytics in Quip live app

Tags: liveapps, quip

We are looking to integrate google analytics into our live app. We are planning to use ReactGA library(https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga) that is readily available for react apps(Since the live app is itself in React). I am not able to record any hits in the google analytics page. Anyone try integrating google analytics into their live apps? Thanks.

Update:
Seems like the app isn't able to reach the ga servers.I see the following error in console:
react-ga.js:889 Refused to load the script 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'unsafe-eval' https://d2i1pl9gz4hwa7.cloudfront.net 'self' https://localhost:8888".

Comment: I tried adding this: 
    "csp_sources": {
        "script_srcs": ["https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"]
    }
to the manifest.json, but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following in the manifest file:

```
"csp_sources": { 
    "script_srcs": ["https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"], 
    "connect_srcs": ["https://www.google-analytics.com"],
    "img_srcs": ["https://www.google-analytics.com"]
}
```

(The script allows access to analytics.js, connect allows the callouts to GA, img allows GA to inject its tracking pixel)

Quip seems to disallow use of cookies, so you when initializing, set the storage to none. You will have to implement your own storage to keep a persistent client id (for example, by using local storage)

```
ReactGA.initialize('UA-XXXXXXXX-1', 
{ 
    debug: true,   
    gaOptions: {
        storage: 'none',
    }
});
```

One final note, this won't work from localhost. You'll need to build and deploy the app for the analytics to work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding this to the manifest.json?

`"csp_sources": { "script_srcs": ["https://www.google-analytics.com"] }`

I think you might need to include the full domain but not the /analytics.js path afterwards.

Comment: Hello Rajeev sorry, but I still keep getting the violation error, even when I include the above line in manifest.json .

Comment: Try this:     "csp_sources": { "script_srcs": ["https://www.google-analytics.com"], "connect_srcs": ["https://www.google-analytics.com"]}