# Content Security Policity

Tags: quip, liveapps

Hey I'm trying to create an app in Quip but I'm getting the following error because I'm trying to connect to Figma API.

Refused to connect to 'https://api.figma.com/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src https://quip-cdn.com 'self'".

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add this site to csp resources in the manifest. Check out this thread: [Google analytics in Quip live app](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/209247/google-analytics-in-quip-live-app)